# Styling treecell with -fx-background works with setStyle() but not setStyleClass()

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

When I apply the style this way:

```
setStyle("-fx-text-fill: #ADADAD; -fx-background: #FCFBA2; -fx-border-radius: 20; -fx-background-radius: 20;")
```

it works - I get a rounded background color fill.

But when I put it in a CSS file (by itself), apply the sheet and add the style to the cell:

```
getStyleClass().add("step-inprogress");
```

using this in the stylesheet:

```
.step-inprogress {
-fx-text-fill: #ADADAD;
-fx-background: #FCFBA2;
-fx-border-radius: 20;
-fx-background-radius: 20;
}
```

Then I don't get the background. The text-fill color is applied, so I know the stylesheet has been loaded and the style has been applied. Just the -fx-background is ignored :(

I'm new to JavaFX and my CSS experience is limited, so I need help understanding what I've done to make this happen.

BTW, I'm using -fx-background instead of -fx-background-color because the latter fills the entire background, ignoring the -fx-background-radius attribute.  If I switch to -fx-background-color, then the color IS applied in either usage.

Comment: Can you create an MCVE? I tried this and it worked fine both ways.

Comment: That is encouraging - good to know it _should_ work. I'll see if I can come up with an example.

Comment: Well now, this is kinda embarassing...I can't produce a MCVE. Simple examples work fine. Which means my code is clearly at fault.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that my code is at fault...and if I had produced an example BEFORE posting this question, well, the question would never have been posted.